# I can't open the link in the new tab when I use angularjs material $mdDialog.confirm()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, browser

I guess the problem appears in the callback 
The browser will block non-human jumps by default, even if I open a new tab and then location url
[image]

```
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
    var url = 'www.google.com';
    var goUrl = window.open();
    goUrl.location = url;
});
```

https://codepen.io/scheinin/pen/JmvEob

Answer (score 0):

Just turn

```
var goUrl = window.open();
goUrl.location = url;
```

Into

```
var goUrl = window.open(url);
```

Comment: @Scheinin what do you mean

Comment: sorry, my English is terrible.What I want to express is that `window.open(url)` still cannot open a new tab in the callback.